# Entity is not updating in nopCommerce 3.0

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, nopcommerce

I have created my custom entity in nopCommerce 3.0. I have successfully implemented Insert/Update/Delete on this entity.
My update will done on custom Entity when Particular event like Product Update Event will called. 
But strangely only the first time my entity is Updated, second time it runs update code successfully but not updated in database.
when I Click Restart Application or put blank space in web.config the entity will now updated but only once, to update second time again I have to put blank space or restart App to update.

So what can be problem here? Caching ? then I have clear caching from MemoryCacheManager class before my update code. but still not updated my entity.

Comment: "_it runs update code successfully but not updated in database_". If you are referring to your `Update` method, then I think you need to show that code in your question so we can see why it doesn't update a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When its being updated, please check the value of Entity's Id. It should have a valid Id.

I had slimier issue other-way around, insert was not working. Then after few hours of debugging, i found one method which builds the entity sets id to a value greater than zero. So insert wont take place.